# Require assistance to convert an stl file of complex (symmetric) voxel geometry to one with smooth surface in Blender

Tags: smooth, stl

newb here.

I want to smoothen the model shown which comprises of voxels. I tried using a smoothen voxels add on, but it still does not solve my issue.

How could I smoothen the mode as accurately as possible, as I need it for experimenting in a wind tunnel. So, the surface should be as uniform as possible.

Or should I not use Blender for this?

[image: Portion of top view]
[image: Side View]

Comment: Hello, maybe use a remesh tool (like the quad one in the Object Data panel > Remesh > Quad)?

Comment: "Or should I not use Blender for this?" What is it exactly that you want to use Blender for here?